# C programming; lvalue required

Tags: c, pointers, lvalue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lvalue required error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218693/lvalue-required-error)

I am having an error in my C program

```
main () {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printf("%d", *arr);
    arr++;
    printf("%d", *arr);
}
```

When I compile this code I get lvalue required error. for the **line with arr++**.
Any Help!

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Show the minimal entire code please. And an array is a pointer constant, you cannot increment that pointer. (you could assign it to some other pointer and increment that other pointer).

Comment: Is this homework? Because it doesn't look like something you would ever actually want to do.

Comment: I just wanted to know the basic difference between a pointer and the array name(i.e the first location pointed by the array).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operand of the pre- and postfix versions of `++` and `--` must be a modifiable lvalue.  Unfortunately, array expressions such as `arr` are *non*-modifiable lvalues, hence your error message.

If you want to walk the array using a pointer expression, you'll have to declare a second pointer and set it to point to the first element of the array.

```
int *p = arr; // or &arr[0] - in this context they evaluate to the same thing
```

Answer (score 5):

`arr` is a constant, you can't change its value. You can add a

```
int *p = arr;
```

And then do a

```
p++;
```

Comment: You should explain here that "arr" isn't merely a constant -- it is an array, not a pointer. Although C makes arrays and pointers look similar, they are not the same sort of thing -- you cannot increment an array.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `arr` is an array and arrays are not lvalues. You need a pointer.

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int *p = &arr;
printf("%d", *p);
p++;
printf("%d", *p);
```

Comment: Isn't &arr an int ** (with some a const in there, of course)?

Comment: @ambq No it is not. In your code you are just taking advantage of the fact that `arr` decays to `&arr`.

Comment: Thanks, it's been a decade and a half since I last programmed in straight C...

Answer (score 2):

`lvalue` generally refers to the value on the left of an assignment (=) operator. Since `arr++` is shorthand for `arr = arr + 1`, that's what it's referring to.

Basically, arr as an array, and there is no support for changing the value of an array. I think you want a pointer to the array. Pointers can be incremented in the way your code attempts to.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is constant, you can not change it's value.

Keep it simple, access the array this way:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printf("arr[0] == %d\n", arr[0]);
    printf("arr[1] == %d\n", arr[1]);
    printf("arr[2] == %d\n", arr[2]);
    printf("arr[3] == %d", arr[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

I recommend [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_%28computer_science%29) documentation for lvalues and rvalues.

And also, this [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) about "Arrays are not pointers".