# lvalue required as left operand of assignment float error

Tags: c, lvalue

Why do I have the error *lvalue required as left operand of assignment error*?

```
   #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
            int x = 2, y = 2;
            float f = y + x /= x / y;
            printf("%d %f\n", x, f);
            return 0;
        }
```

And why is the output false here?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        int x = 1, y = 2;
        if (x && y == 1)
            printf("true\n");
        else
            printf("false\n");
    }
```

I thought that when the both values are different from 0, && will always result a 1

Comment: `float f = y + x /= x / y;` - what is this supposed to mean?

Comment: There's a lot going on here and not all of it makes sense. What's the intent with `x /= x`?

Comment: This is an exercise from a website.

Answer (score 0):

C makes a distinction between *lvalues* and *rvalues*. Here's [a snippet](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/12/15/understanding-lvalues-and-rvalues-in-c-and-c/) that sums up the difference:

> An lvalue (locator value) represents an object that occupies some
>   identifiable location in memory (i.e. has an address).

On this line, you violate this by mixing the two types:

```
float f = y + x /= x / y;
```

There is nowhere in memory specified to hold the result of `x / y`. You can read more about this on [many Stack pages](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D%20lvalue).

As for the second question, `if (x && y == 1)` is false because `y == 1` is false. The statement is equivalent to `x && 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find multiple answers on SO describing what an lvalue is (an expression that designates an object, as opposed to merely a value), and that address other instances of "lvalue required" errors.  For example,

- [lvalue required](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3896637/2402272)
- [lvalue required error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8218693/2402272)
- [Error: lvalue required in this simple C code? (Ternary with assignment?)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6966299/2402272)

Basically, the error means that the program contains an assignment or combined operator / assignment expression whose left-hand operand does not designate an object, such that the assignment part is nonsense.

Sometimes these arise because operator precedence yields a different order of operations than the author of the code supposed or wanted, and unless the code you presented is intentionally erroneous, that's the case with it.  Specifically, in

> ```
>             float f = y + x /= x / y;
> ```

, the problem is with the initializer expression, `y + x /= x / y`.  Presumably, the intention was that this would be evaluated as `y + (x /= (x / y))`, which has a well-defined value and a well-defined side effect on the value of `x`.

However, the precedence of the assignment and opassignment operators such as `/=` is very low, so the expression is *actually* interpreted as equivalent to `(y + x) /= (x / y)`.  `y + x` is not an lvalue (it can be evaluated, but it does not designate an object), therefore it is not an acceptable left operand of the `/=` operator.  This is the reason for the error.

Your second question involves another operator precedence issue.  The `&&` operator has lower precedence than the `==` operator, so `x && y == 1` is equivalent to `x && (y == 1)`.  With your initializations, the right-hand operand of `&&` evaluates to 0, so the overall expression evaluates to 0.  If the intention was to test whether `x && y` evaluates to a truthy value, then this is a case of shooting oneself in the foot, because leaving off the `== 1` part would both be more conventional and yield the desired result.