# C++ checking two versions of functions

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, point

I'm writing an exercise in C++, and I wrote a code that seems to me to be valid, but I don't know for sure, as I'm still a beginner, can someone check it and tell me if they are the same or not.

The solution code:

```
Point *PointArray::get( const int pos) {
    return pos >= 0 && pos < size ? points + pos : NULL;
}
```

and my code is:

```
Point* PointArray::get (const int position) {
    return &(data[position]);
}
```

I realize that in my code i have to check the conditions to check if to return a null pointer or not, but apart from that, is my version the same as `points + pos`

`points` & `data` are arrays of Point class, i named mine data, the solution named it points.

EDIT:

my code after i added the condition to it:

```
Point* PointArray::get (const int position) {
    return ((position >= 0 && position < size) ? &(data[position]) : NULL);
}
```

Comment: Besides the checking that pos >= 0, they are the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a nutshell, they do the same thing. There are some differences though:

1) The solution code checks the array bounds. Your solution does not.

2) The solution uses pointer arithmetic and avoids an extra dereference/address-of operation (most compilers will optimize this for you).
See [Efficiency: arrays vs pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305770/efficiency-arrays-vs-pointers).

Comment: Yeh, I editied my code to include the consitions.
Thanks David

Comment: Discussion of differences in 2, seems like modern compilers do optimize this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305770/efficiency-arrays-vs-pointers

Comment: @David Z.: not relevant here, there one of the access is without the position shift.