# C- Why is for loop pointer indexing faster?

Tags: c, optimization

I’m currently looking on how to optimise my C code. I found [this](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2015/01/c-cpp-code-optimization/) page which says, in section 10, that pointer address indexing for  the for loop would be faster than doing it with the non pointer arithmetic syntax. my question is why and if that’s even still true with all the modern compiler optimisations

```
If you access members of array like this:

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) nArray[i]=nSomeValue;
Instead of the above code, the following is better:

for(int* ptrInt = nArray; ptrInt< nArray+n; ptrInt++) *ptrInt=nSomeValue;
```

Comment: Don't link images: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions. For example to show examples of the "pointer arithmetic" loop. (PS. Links to external sites can go bad, always make questions self-contained.)

Comment: This smells like snake oil.

Comment: As for pointer arithmetic, for any pointer *or array* `p` and index `i`, the expression `p[i]` is *exactly* equal to `*(p + i)`. So any "normal" array access and indexing is still being a form of pointer arithmetic.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2305770/efficiency-arrays-vs-pointers

Comment: That’s exactly what I thought, why should it be faster it is pretty much exactly the same, function wise

Comment: This may have been partly true a long time ago with simple non optimizing compilers. Today with modern compilers, both methods will most likely result in the same code.

Comment: Okay thanks for the confirmation, I’m not too trusted with C optimising yet…

Comment: The result is the same for both versions: https://godbolt.org/z/x7f54vjoz The code at the beginning of the functions are a little bit different, but the loop is the same.

Comment: The worst you could do is premature optimization. Optimize **only** if your code is too slow. Otherwise let it be readable at the maximum level. Write what you intend, not what you think the compiler should be forced into. -- And even if you optimize, such minor gains as shown in the (in parts plain wrong) page you link, refactor, and use a better algorithm. If that's not possible, you can only save corner cases. You will never make an Arduino do complex video manipulation, for example.

Comment: Yeah absolutely but I’m optimising for a few low-level mathematical operations so I guess it makes sense for then.

Comment: If I’m already here, another very small question. 
Does it make a difference if I return a “return value” via a pointer in the parameters or via a return statement if I am gonna allocate the memory for the return anyway?

Comment: I can confirm by experience that, 35 years ago, such tricks really improved efficiency of the code. 35 years ago.

Comment: Okay, I’m only 19 so I don’t have that much experience. sorry

Comment: But I’m really grateful for your wisdom :)